# Why do tuples in a list comprehension need parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples, list-comprehension

It is well known that tuples are not defined by parentheses, but commas. [Quote from documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas

Therefore:

```
myVar1 = 'a', 'b', 'c'
type(myVar1)
# Result:
<type 'tuple'>
```

Another striking example is this:

```
myVar2 = ('a')
type(myVar2)
# Result:
<type 'str'>  

myVar3 = ('a',)
type(myVar3)
# Result:
<type 'tuple'>
```

Even the single-element tuple needs a comma, and parentheses are always used just to avoid confusion. **My question is:** Why can't we omit parentheses of arrays in a list comprehension? For example:

```
myList1 = ['a', 'b']
myList2 = ['c', 'd']

print([(v1,v2) for v1 in myList1 for v2 in myList2])
# Works, result:
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]

print([v1,v2 for v1 in myList1 for v2 in myList2])
# Does not work, result:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Isn't the second list comprehension just syntactic sugar for the following loop, which does work?

```
myTuples = []
for v1 in myList1:
    for v2 in myList2:
        myTuple = v1,v2
        myTuples.append(myTuple)
print myTuples
# Result:
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python's grammar is [LL(1)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), meaning that it only looks ahead one symbol when parsing.

```
[(v1, v2) for v1 in myList1 for v2 in myList2]
```

Here, the parser sees something like this.

```
[ # An opening bracket; must be some kind of list
[( # Okay, so a list containing some value in parentheses
[(v1
[(v1,
[(v1, v2
[(v1, v2)
[(v1, v2) for # Alright, list comprehension
```

However, without the parentheses, it has to make a decision earlier on.

```
[v1, v2 for v1 in myList1 for v2 in myList2]

[ # List-ish thing
[v1 # List containing a value; alright
[v1, # List containing at least two values
[v1, v2 # Here's the second value
[v1, v2 for # Wait, what?
```

A parser which backtracks tends to be notoriously slow, so LL(1) parsers do not backtrack. Thus, the ambiguous syntax is forbidden.

Comment: It turns out this answer is wrong. See [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013005/68587) or [this more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986850/why-does-creating-a-list-of-tuples-using-list-comprehension-requires-parentheses?noredirect=1) for details.

Answer (score 3):

As I felt ["because the grammar forbids it"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Grammar/Grammar) to be a little too snarky, I came up with a *reason*.

It begins parsing the expression as a list/set/tuple and is expecting a `,` and instead encounters a `for` token.

For example:

```
$ python3.6 test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    [a, b for a, b in c]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

tokenizes as follows:

```
$ python3.6 -m tokenize test.py
0,0-0,0:            ENCODING       'utf-8'        
1,0-1,1:            OP             '['            
1,1-1,2:            NAME           'a'            
1,2-1,3:            OP             ','            
1,4-1,5:            NAME           'b'            
1,6-1,9:            NAME           'for'          
1,10-1,11:          NAME           'a'            
1,11-1,12:          OP             ','            
1,13-1,14:          NAME           'b'            
1,15-1,17:          NAME           'in'           
1,18-1,19:          NAME           'c'            
1,19-1,20:          OP             ']'            
1,20-1,21:          NEWLINE        '\n'           
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Answer (score 3):

There was no parser issue that motivated this restriction. Contrary to Silvio Mayolo's answer, an LL(1) parser could have parsed the no-parentheses syntax just fine. The parentheses were optional in early versions of the original list comprehension patch; they were only made mandatory to make the meaning clearer.

Quoting Guido van Rossum back in 2000, in a [response](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/QXZTOKUJPBYJRNAX32EFI2YRX3RXNRIE/) to someone worried that `[x, y for ...]` would cause parser issues,

> Don't worry.  Greg Ewing had no problem expressing this in Python's
>   own grammar, which is about as restricted as parsers come.  (It's
>   LL(1), which is equivalent to pure recursive descent with one
>   lookahead token, i.e. no backtracking.)
>
> Here's Greg's grammar:
>
> ```
> atom: ... | '[' [testlist [list_iter]] ']' | ...
>   list_iter: list_for | list_if
>   list_for: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist [list_iter]
>   list_if: 'if' test [list_iter]
> ```
>
> Note that before, the list syntax was `'[' [testlist] ']'`.  Let me
>   explain it in different terms:
>
> The parser parses a series comma-separated expressions.  Previously,
>   it was expecting `']'` as the sole possible token following this. 
>   After the change, `'for'` is another possible following token.  This
>   is no problem at all for any parser that knows how to parse matching
>   parentheses!
>
> If you'd rather not support `[x, y for ...]` because it's ambiguous
>   (to the human reader, not to the parser!), we can change the grammar
>   to something like:
>
> ```
> '[' test [',' testlist | list_iter] ']'
> ```
>
> (Note that `|` binds less than concatenation, and `[...]` means an
>   optional part.)

Also see the [next response](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/JR37WBPDZ4CXJRP4L7G3AEN5DUUWKHYE/) in the thread, where Greg Ewing runs

```
>>> seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [x, x*2 for x in seq]
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10)]
```

on an early version of the list comprehension patch, and it works just fine.