# Why does creating a list of tuples using list comprehension requires parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As noted in [Functional Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), to create a list of tuples using list comprehension, parentheses must be used. Particularly, this is expressed in the document in the following quote.

> To avoid introducing an ambiguity into Python’s grammar, if *expression*
>   is creating a tuple, it must be surrounded with parentheses.

So, as examples:

```
[x, y for x in seq1 for y in seq2]  # This is a syntex error
[(x, y) for x in seq1 for y in seq2]  # This is a correct expression of list of tuples using list comprehension
```

What ambiguity is avoided by forcing the use of parentheses in expressing a list of tuples using list comprehension?

Comment: @Georgy: Unfortunately, the currently accepted answer on that question is wrong. (It's what I would have guessed before finding confirmation otherwise, but it's still wrong.)

Comment: See also [Why do tuples in a list comprehension need parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220279/why-do-tuples-in-a-list-comprehension-need-parentheses), which has the incorrect answer @user2357112 refers to.

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of mailing list digging, I've found a pretty unambiguous statement that the parser was fine with it. The parentheses were made mandatory to make the meaning clearer. Here's a [quote](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/QXZTOKUJPBYJRNAX32EFI2YRX3RXNRIE/) from Guido back in 2000 on the python-dev mailing list:

> Don't worry.  Greg Ewing had no problem expressing this in Python's
>   own grammar, which is about as restricted as parsers come.  (It's
>   LL(1), which is equivalent to pure recursive descent with one
>   lookahead token, i.e. no backtracking.)
>
> Here's Greg's grammar:
>
> ```
> atom: ... | '[' [testlist [list_iter]] ']' | ...
>   list_iter: list_for | list_if
>   list_for: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist [list_iter]
>   list_if: 'if' test [list_iter]
> ```
>
> Note that before, the list syntax was `'[' [testlist] ']'`.  Let me
>   explain it in different terms:
>
> The parser parses a series comma-separated expressions.  Previously,
>   it was expecting `']'` as the sole possible token following this. 
>   After the change, `'for'` is another possible following token.  This
>   is no problem at all for any parser that knows how to parse matching
>   parentheses!
>
> If you'd rather not support `[x, y for ...]` because it's ambiguous
>   (to the human reader, not to the parser!), we can change the grammar
>   to something like:
>
> ```
> '[' test [',' testlist | list_iter] ']'
> ```
>
> (Note that `|` binds less than concatenation, and `[...]` means an
>   optional part.)

Also see the [next response](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/JR37WBPDZ4CXJRP4L7G3AEN5DUUWKHYE/) in the thread, where Greg Ewing runs

```
>>> seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [x, x*2 for x in seq]
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10)]
```

on an early version of the list comprehension patch, and it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> As you see, on output tuples are always enclosed in parentheses, so that nested tuples are interpreted correctly; they may be input with or without surrounding parentheses, although often parentheses are necessary anyway (if the tuple is part of a larger expression). It is not possible to assign to the individual items of a tuple, however it is possible to create tuples which contain mutable objects, such as lists.

Inside a list comprehension tuples are nested inside a list. So they must be enclosed in parentheses. But when not being nested e.g. `the_tuples = 'a','b','c'` they are not necessary because they are automatically recognized as tuples then.