# Tuple syntax in Python

Tags: python

I am having some trouble understanding parts of syntax. Particularly when parentheses `()` are required for tuples.

For instance, this piece of code below:

```
c={'a':10,'b':1,'c':22,'d':10}

tup=a,b=4,5

print(a)
print(b)
print(tup)

newlist=[(x,y) for y,x in c.items()]

print(newlist)
```

The output for this code is:

```
4
5
(4, 5)
[(10, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (22, 'c'), (10, 'd')]
```

When trying to take the parentheses out of x, y in the list comprehension statement, I get a traceback. However, every other tuple in this code *does not* require parenthesis.

What am I missing? Why is it that Python understands `a,b` to be a tuple but not `x,y` when it is in a list comprehension statement?

It seems to me that Python is inconsistent with tuple syntax. I tried taking the parentheses out and putting them back to understand how the syntax works.

Comment: `a,b` isn't strictly a tuple, it's a [target list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-target_list)

Comment: Probably this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48220279/3001761

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! yes, it is a very similar question to the one you linked. I loved how he explained that one too. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parentheses are needed to give priority to operators. Consider the two following lines of code, which differ only by the parentheses:

```py
tup_a = 3, 4 + 10, 20
tup_b = (3, 4) + (10, 20)
```

The first line defines a tuple `tup_a` of 3 elements, `(3, 14, 20)`. The second line defines two tuples `(3, 4)` and `(10, 20)`, then concatenates them into a tuple of four elements, `(3, 4, 10, 20)`.

Wrong parentheses can easily result in an error:

```py
tup_c = 3, 4 * 10, 20
tup_d = (3, 4) * (10, 20)
```

The first line defines a tuple of 3 elements, `(3, 40, 20)`. The second line results in a `TypeError` because it defines two tuples `(3, 4)` and `(10, 20)` and then attempts to multiply them, but the multiplication operator `*` doesn't know what to do with tuples.

You encountered a similar issue. Consider the following lines of codes:

```py
x = 42
c = {'a': 10, 'b': 1, 'c': 22, 'd': 10}

l_a = [(x, y) for y,x in c.items()]  # [(10, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (22, 'c'), (10, 'd')]
l_b = [x, (y for y,x in c.items())]  # [42, <generator object>]
l_c = [x, y for y,x in c.items()]    # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This code correctly defines two lists `l_a` and `l_b`, but then it raises a `SyntaxError` when trying to define `l_c`.

The designers of python decided that the syntax for `l_c` was ambiguous, and you should add parentheses to explicitly specify whether you meant the same thing as `l_a` or as `l_b`.

Note that the line of code for `l_b` would raise a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` if I hadn't added `x = 42` at the beginning, since the role of `x` is not the same in `l_b` as it is in `l_a`.

Comment: Right. Generator expressions, by definition, must be parenthesized, but there are some exceptions (such as when the generator expression is the lone argument to a function call).

Comment: @chepner Yes, originally I wanted to write that, but the error raised by `[x, y for y,x in c.items()] ` is not the same as the error raised for `f(3, d for d in c)` for instance, so I decided to not give any details.(`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the list comprehension, versus `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized` for the function call)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I understand now that it, as you said, the creators of python simply decided that in the case of list comprehension it is too ambiguous to leave the statement without parenthesis. I guess it is just surprising to me that they decided that in the other cases it is not too ambiguous.

Comment: @jonohashmo As chepner pointed out, I think the parentheses are necessary because of the generator-expression, not because of the tuple. Generator-expressions are these "inline `for` loops" and they always need to be parenthesized. I think the idea is that the comma `,` has relatively low priority, so python *would* interpret `l_c` the same way as `l_b` and not as `l_a`, *but* it has been decided that generator-expressions must always be surrounded in parentheses, so if it's `l_b`, then the parentheses are needed. I'm not entirely sure about this, which is why I didn't write that in the answer